# sort last login time

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

i have such kind of output

```
2015.08.03 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123,
2015.08.05 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.06 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.07 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.10 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.14 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.17 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.19 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.24 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.26 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.31 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.11 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.14 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.16 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.17 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.18 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.20 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.24 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.27 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.28 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.29 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
2015.08.30 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
```

What I need is to see when the found users (with personal codes `12345678912` and `98765432187`) were last logged in. In output I want to see the last line (without commas too). Like this:

```
2015.08.31 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123
2015.08.30 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873
```

And one more thing, the date number might not be the same. Last login date can be also `2015.08.02` or `2015.08.17` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach gives the last login time for any personalCode:

```
f=file; cat "$f" | awk '{print $3}' | uniq | while read number; do grep "$number" "$f" | tail -n 1; done
```

outputs:

```
2015.08.31 personalCode: 12345678912, uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123,
2015.08.30 personalCode: 98765432187, uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's just what I needed!

Comment: This is **NOT**  an eficient aproach , to many processes an other issues. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

The entrys *seems to be sorted* so you can use `tac` + `awk`:

```
$ tac log_file|gawk '!($3 in a){gsub(",", "");print}{a[$3]=1}' FS='( |,)' 
2015.08.30 personalCode: 98765432187 uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873
2015.08.31 personalCode: 12345678912 uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123
```

Or just **one process**:

```
$ gawk '{a[$3]=$0}END{for (i in a){gsub(",", "",a[i]);print a[i]}}' FS='( |,)' log_file
2015.08.31 personalCode: 12345678912 uid: 016b353f-5b45-4ef6-b150-123456789123
2015.08.30 personalCode: 98765432187 uid: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-987654321873
```

**Peformance**

```
$ wc -l log_file
34386 log_file
```

*Accepted solution:*

```
$ time (cat log_file| awk '{print $3}' | uniq | while read number; do grep "$number" "$f" >/dev/null | tail -n 1; done)

real    0m58.868s
user    0m52.978s
sys 0m8.732s
```

`gawk` *solution:*

```
$ time gawk '{a[$3]=$0}END{for (i in a){gsub(",", "",a[i]);print a[i]}}' FS='( |,)' log_file>/dev/null

real    0m0.120s
user    0m0.119s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to select the given users. Then, sort the output by time (`-k1,1` means from the 1st column to the 1st column, `r` means reversed), and then unify on the personal code, i.e. the 3rd column.

```
< input.txt grep 'personalCode: \(12345678912\|98765432187\)' \
    | sort -rk1,1 \
    | sort -uk3,3
```

Comment: but I don't know the given users... in this example I have them, but i need to find in my log file all users who was logged in (by the last year) and what was their last login date.

Comment: Btw your answer is quite helpful for me. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: @sergei: then just sort the whole file.